# Thumb is on top of the seekbar

Tags: tooltip, thumbnails, android-seekbar

I am trying to design a seekbar with a thumb that contains the progress.
Below is the image how it is expected to be:
[image]

Below is my xml for the seekbar:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_50"
                    android:max="9"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:progress="1"
                    android:splitTrack="false"
                    android:thumbOffset="@dimen/dp_50"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/ic_tooltip2"
                    />
```

But my thumb is coming on top of the seekbar instead of coming above it. This is my current result :
[image]

How can I get the expected result and how to place the text on the thumb image.